# Send basic email with file (e.g. PDF) attachment

Tags: java

I have a web app that generates a PDF with iText (saving it to directory on server) and now I need to generate a simple (e.g. not HTML) email and add it as an attachment.

There's a lot of info out there how to send an email with file attachment. For example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Of course, it'd be nice to have a reusable component to do this. Here's a nice blog for this:

http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java

This last blog article is written for Java 1.3 and 1.4. I'm using Java SE 1.6 SDK.

Question: Is this blog still relevant for 1.6, or is there a better way to do this? Since I don't code in Java much, I'm hoping someone can point me to any established links/practices illustrating how to do this for more recent Java SDKs. Or, just give me a sanity check that the codejava blog above is still current and is best practice.

Comment: I recommend this method: "Sending Email with Attachment" http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SendAttachment.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can get fiddly with multi-part-mime stuff etc.  Try a higher level abstraction such as [Apache Commons Mail](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) or even [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html)

Comment: Thanks earcam, I had no idea these solutions existed. The Apache Commons Mail looks like a nice solution.